# Espresso Android : Cannot scroll and click on a specific item in the list preference

Tags: listview, automated-tests, robotium, android-testing, android-espresso

Android Espresso Test: Have to click on an item which on number index 14 and is not visible on the screen. First need to scroll to this particular item and then click. Successfully able to swipeUp() which goes all the way to the bottom but the item I want to click is not visible on the screen. Any help? Tried the following it is not working:

```
onData(instanceOf(ListPreference.class)).inAdapterView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.list))).atPosition(14).perform(scrollTo());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please give a try for

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list)).atPosition(14).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using onData you do not need to take care about the scrolling. Espresso itself will make sure that you will click at necessary item. But you should specify what item you want to click. You can take a look at the example how to write onData statement here (link removed as it points to malware site)

Answer (score 0):

```
onData(hasEntry(equalTo(ListViewSample.ROW_TEXT),is("List item: 20")))
.check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

The above line of code will scroll the List till row 20th an check the element on 2oth row is displayed.